why does my else statement not working after i press E the first time?
In Unity, I have a "human" as a GameObject and a "mecha" prefab. The goal is to disable the human GameObject and Instantiate the mecha prefab when the player hits E on the keyboard, and when the user presses E again, destroy the instantiated object and enable the human GameObject.
So far, changing from human to mecha works, but when I press E again, it does nothing. I have tried adding Debug.Logs, and still, human to mecha works but mecha to human does nothing. It's like the else statement is not readable or executable.
Is it because when I press E the first time it disables the human GameObject? Here is the current code I'm using:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MechaSummoner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject character;
    public GameObject mechaPrefab;
    public Transform summonPoint;
    public KeyCode summonKey = KeyCode.E;

    private GameObject mechaInstance;
    public bool isInMecha = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(summonKey))
        {
            if (!isInMecha)
            {
                SummonMecha();
            }
            else
            {
                character.SetActive(true);      
                ExitMecha();
            }
        }
    }

    void SummonMecha()
    {
        mechaInstance = Instantiate(mechaPrefab, summonPoint.position, summonPoint.rotation);
        character.SetActive(false);
        character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
        mechaInstance.GetComponent<MechaController>().enabled = true;
        isInMecha = true;

    }

    void ExitMecha()
    {
        Destroy(mechaInstance);
        character.SetActive(true);
        character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
        isInMecha = false;

    }
}

"CharacterController" is the movement scripts for the human GameObject, and "MechaController" is the movement script for the mecha.

I HAVE FOUND THE PROBLEM AND THE SOLUTION!
Problem: i put the script to disable [GameObject A] into [GameObject ] itself so when i run the program, after i disable it (by pressing E), i cannot use the code anymore because the GameObject is disabled.
Solution: Making a new parent and move the code to the new parent and assign each GameObjects in the inspector.
by doing this, the parent will have the program to get the input and be able to disable the GameObject (pilot) without disabling itself. Keep in mind that the code is the same and nothing changed, just the location of the code.
